# i18next::languageUtils: rejecting language code not found in supportedLngs: en

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have developed a react application where I am using **i18next**, **react-i18next**, **i18next-http-backend** for localization.

In my application, I wanted to support only **en-us** language code for now and maybe will add further languages in the future, so I have added the below settings for i18n configuration.

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: "en-us",
    fallbackLng: "en-us",
    debug: true,
    supportedLngs: ["en-us"],
    lowerCaseLng: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ","
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

and placed the localization translation file at **public/locales/en-us/translation.json**. I have added **supportedLngs** because I want my **i18next-http-backend** should load only supported languages.

When I run the application I am getting a below warning

```
i18next::languageUtils: rejecting language code not found in supportedLngs: en
```

As per the document here: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options

I have also tried to set the **nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true** but then my translation file is not loaded and I am getting another weird warning as below:

```
i18next::languageUtils: rejecting language code not found in supportedLngs: en-us
i18next::languageUtils: rejecting language code not found in supportedLngs: en
```

How I can get away from the warning? am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the load option to “currentOnly”
https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#languages-namespaces-resources